How to make VSCode commit command NOT use the --quiet option?
I have this problem, but when using SSH remote development on an actually remote machine (no WSL) and I need to be able to use the GUI commit button.
From what I have read, the culprit to the GPG not prompting for passphrase is the fact that VS Code uses git -c user.useConfigOnly=true commit --quiet --allow-empty-message --file - -S to commit stuff.
If the --quiet option is removed, gpg asks for the passphrase.
How do modify the git command VS Code uses?

Try with:

Open VS Code settings by clicking on the gear icon in the lower-left corner and selecting "Settings."
In the search bar, type "git config" to filter the settings.
Click on "Edit in settings.json" to open the settings file.
Add the following configuration to the file:

  "git.config": {                                                                                                                                                                                       
    "commit.quiet": false                                                                                                                                                                               
  }   


Unknown settings. Does not change anything. How did you come up with this solution?
